# How does a Named Credential with a custom Auth. Provider check token validity?

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider, accesstoken, authproviderpluginclass

When using a custom OAuth 2.0 provider as an extension of `AuthProviderPluginClass` for a Named Credential how does Salesforce check whether the current token is valid before attempting to request a new one? What's the flow?

In the docs for Connected Apps there are mentions of token introspection and other good stuff but I haven't been able to find anything on custom Auth. Providers or Named Credentials. Here is some reference material:

[AuthProviderPluginClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm)

[OAuth Tokens and Scopes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5)

[Named Credentials: Choose an Authentication Protocol](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_auth_protocols.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce closely follows the [Oauth2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) for a Named Credential OAuth2.0 flow.

When you save and start the Authentication flow, the page reference method `initiate` is called where your class has the URL to navigate to and complete the Oauth2.0 flow.

Once Authentication is successful the callback method `handleCallback` should have the logic to invoke the access token endpoint and get access and refresh tokens.

**How does Salesforce check whether the current token is valid before attempting to request a new one?**

This is based on the HTTP response code you get back making HTTP outnpund callout using the Named Credential in apex. If the HTTP response code returned is **401** then salesforce uses the refresh token to get the new access token. This is not documented well enough, however, there is some reference [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313355&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1).